# Mahout command line example

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I have installed Hadoop and Mahout.

I tested Hadoop code with an example, it works fine.

Now how to test Mahout on Hadoop ?

when I executed the following command

```
mahout recommenditembased -s SIMILARITY_LOGLIKELIHOOD -i /home/hduser/a.txt -o /output --numRecommendations 25
```

I am getting this error

```
Running on hadoop, using /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
ERROR: Could not find mahout-examples-*.job in /opt/apache-mahout-distribution-0.11.0 or /opt/apache-mahout-distribution-0.11.0/examples/target, please run 'mvn install' to create the .job file
```

How to solve this and please provide some command line example for running a Mahout example code

Mahout Version :0.11.0

Answer (score 0):

just switch to Mahout installed directory and execute the command.
In my case it is like: /usr/lib/mahout/mahout-0.8-cdh5.0.5
cd /usr/lib/mahout/mahout-0.8-cdh5.0.5
[root@C15738 mahout-0.8-cdh5.0.5]# hadoop jar mahout-core-0.8-cdh5.0.5-job.jar org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob -Dmapred.input.dir=/input_data/MovieList1.txt -Dmapred.output.dir=mahout_output_27N --usersFile /input_data/users.txt  --booleanData --similarityClassname SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE --tempDir /temp
.....
just check your command from Mahout installed directory on hadoop cluster.